# How to use foreach in view using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem with the view of codeigniter.

I want to retain the header.

Example: the header contains the main title of the view like Product Number, Product kind and Product quantity. Below is the list of all available products.

I'd try to code but it will repeat the top header which is the Product Number, Product Kind and Product quantity.

The result should be like this.

```
Product number: 0011
Product Kind: Beverages
Product Quantity: 1000
--------------------------
Fit n Right
Coke
Pepsi
Lemon Juice
Gatorade
etc...

something like that. But my output code was: 

Product number: 0011
Product Kind: Beverages
Product Quantity: 1000
--------------------------
Fit n Right

Product number: 0011
Product Kind: Beverages
Product Quantity: 1000
--------------------------
Coke

Product number: 0011
Product Kind: Beverages
Product Quantity: 1000
--------------------------
Pepsi

Product number: 0011
Product Kind: Beverages
Product Quantity: 1000
--------------------------
Lemon Juice
```

and so on...

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Beverages</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

 $funds=strtoupper($fundagent);

   if ($eid_num >0){
       foreach($eid_num as $row):
            $eid=$row->eid;
            $eseries=$row->becno;
            $amount=$row->amount;
            $rescenter=$row->res_center;

 ?>
 <div id="entrystyle" align="center">
table class="box-table-a" valign="top">
   <thead>
     <tr>
         <th colspan="7">Control System</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
 <?php 
     echo form_open('/beverage/update-data-entry/'.$eid.'/'.strtolower($eseries)); 
 ?>   
 <tr class="gb">
     <td id="fontstyle">
           <label>Budget Earmarking Control No.</label>
           <input type="text" name="becno" id="controlno" size="15" required="required" value="<?php echo $eseries; ?>" onblur="copy_control_no()" readonly="readonly" />
    </td>
    <td id="fontstyle">
        <label>Amount</label>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" size="15" required="required" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" readonly="readonly">
   </td>`
```

this portion i want to repeat or loop

```
    `<td id="fontstyle">
        <label>Responsibility Center</label>
        <input type="text" name="responsible" id="responsible" size="15" required="required" value="<?php echo $rescenter; ?>" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: please post some code.. Or atleast post the variable(the array) that you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function build_view($flake) {
        $this->data['content'] = $this->load->view($flake, $this->data, TRUE);
        $this->load->view('header', $this->data);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Controller:

```
public function func(){
    .......
    $data['result'] = $this->model->myfunction();  // return resultset from DB
    $this->load->view('folder/filename', $data);
    ........
}
```

View:

```
<?php 
foreach($result as $value) 
{
     echo $value.'<br/>';
}

?>
```

I think you will get some idea from this.

Comment: yes, that is what am i using but that code repeat the header title, i want that it will display the header title which is also come from the db and below is the list.